# React.js - setDragImage on draggable element

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, reactjs, draggable

I'm trying to swap out the default image that the browser uses when I drag a draggable element (in this case the `ul` below). Here is my code. I'm not getting any errors - it just doesn't work, and I'm left with the default image used by the browser.

```
drag(e) {
  let img = new Image()
  img.src = 'https://some-image.png'
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0)
}

render() {
  return(
    <ul draggable="true" onDrag={(e) => {this.drag(e)}>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The image is not yet loaded when you call `setDragImage()`. I handled this by creating the image on mount and storing it in state:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://some-image.png';
    img.onload = () => this.setState({ dragImg: img });
 }
 drag(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this.state.dragImg, 0, 0);
 }
```

Comment: So wait, you have to create the drag image before `drag` is invoked, and do this for every draggable item, regardless of whether it is actually getting dragged? So if I have hundreds of draggable elements I also have to have a ghost image in RAM for any of them that happen to be dragged? That can't be right.